# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable in Django unittests for message

Tags: django, unit-testing

Am trying to do a unit test for a view that returns a message when some input is duplicated in the database.it gives me the error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

Here is the **view**

```
@login_required
def worker_create(request):
    worker_create_form = WorkerCreateForm(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if worker_create_form.is_valid():
            form = worker_create_form.save(commit=False)
            phone = form.phone
            check_phone = Worker.objects.filter(phone=phone)
            if check_phone.count() != 0:
                messages.error(request, 'رقم الهاتف مستخدم من قبل')
            else:
                form.save()
                return redirect('worker_list')
    else:
        worker_create_form = WorkerCreateForm(request.POST)
    context = {
        'worker_create_form': worker_create_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'erp_system/worker/create.html', context)
```

and here are the **tests** I've created for it

```
class WorkerCreateTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        User.objects.create_user(username='test_user', email='test@gmail.com', password='test_password')
        branch = Branch.objects.create(name='test branch')
        Worker.objects.create(name="ay btngan ", phone='01207199086', branch=branch)

    def test_get_request_unauthenticated(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('worker_create'))
        url = reverse('worker_create')
        self.assertRedirects(response, '/login/?next=' + url)

    def test_get_request_authenticated(self):
        self.client.login(username='test_user', password='test_password')
        response = self.client.get(reverse('worker_create'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed('erp_system/worker/create.html')

    def test_post_request_empty_data(self):
        self.client.login(username='test_user', password='test_password')
        response = self.client.post(reverse('worker_create'), {})
        self.assertFormError(response, 'worker_create_form', 'name', 'This field is required.')
        self.assertFormError(response, 'worker_create_form', 'phone', 'This field is required.')
        self.assertFormError(response, 'worker_create_form', 'branch', 'This field is required.')

    def test_post_request_invalid_data(self):
        self.client.login(username='test_user', password='test_password')
        branch = Branch.objects.create(name='test again ')
        name = 'just a name'
        for i in range(300):
            name += 'h'
        response = self.client.post(reverse('worker_create'),
                                    {'name': name, 'phone': '01207199086', 'branch': branch.id})
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_post_request_duplicated_phone(self):
        self.client.login(username='test_user', password='test_password')
        branch = Branch.objects.create(name='test again ')
        response = self.client.post(reverse('worker_create'),
                                    {'name': 'test worker', 'phone': '01207199086', 'branch': branch.id})
        print(response)
        messages = list(response.context['messages'])
        self.assertEqual(len(messages), 1)
        self.assertEqual(str(messages[0]), 'رقم الهاتف مستخدم من قبل')

    def test_post_request_valid_data(self):
        self.client.login(username='test_user', password='test_password')
        branch = Branch.objects.create(name='test branch1234')
        name = 'new valid name'
        response = self.client.post(reverse('worker_create'),
                                    {'name': name, 'branch': branch.id, 'phone': '0151951115'})
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
```

**Important**
I noticed when I added `print(response)` that it gives me `HttpResponseRedirect` not just `HttpResponse` what means there is no context given. Why it using redirect in here!?

Comment: Because of the `return redirect('worker_list')` in the `worker_create` view? You here make a POST request, hence this is *expected* behavior.

Comment: Here you made a *successfull* POST. Note that separate tests work *independently* of each other. Hence actions done in the former have, given you do not use some "tricks", no impact on other tests. So the previous test that adds the first phone number, does no longer exist.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes that was the problem, just create a new object inside the same test  `Worker.objects.create(name=" just a name ", phone='01207199086', branch=branch)` then sending a post request with the same number solved the case and brought the message. Please submit your suggestion as an answer so I approve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test `test_post_request_duplicated_phone`, you make a POST request to the `worker_create`, and you expect to retrieve an error, because there exists already a record for the given `phone`.

The [documentation on tests [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#testcase) however mentions that:

> A `TestCase`, on the other hand, does not truncate tables after a test. Instead, it **encloses the test code in a database transaction** that is **rolled back at the end of the test**. This guarantees that the rollback at the end of the test **restores the database to its initial state**.

So that means that, unless you implement some "tricks" to prevent this, the side-effects that one test has (on the database) will be gone when you enter a second test. This makes sense, since reordering the tests should not result in a different outcome.

You can however create such `Worker` object in your test in advance, and thus make sure that the test will indeed error:

```
def test_post_request_duplicated_phone(self):
    self.client.login(username='test_user', password='test_password')
    branch = Branch.objects.create(name='test again ')
    Worker.objects.create(name=" just a name ", phone='01207199086', branch=branch)
    response = self.client.post(reverse('worker_create'),
                                {'name': 'test worker', 'phone': '01207199086', 'branch': branch.id})
    print(response)
    messages = list(response.context['messages'])
    self.assertEqual(len(messages), 1)
    self.assertEqual(str(messages[0]), 'رقم الهاتف مستخدم من قبل')
```